# Help with biblatex, no date

Tags: biblatex

I have another problem with `biblatex` (I'm sorry but it's the first time that I use the `biblatex` package). In the .bib file I wrote

```
@article {amberg:artinian, 
author = {Amberg, B.},     
title = "Artinian and noetherian factorized groups",
journaltitle = {Rend. Sem. Mat. Univ. Padova},
date = {1976},   
volume = {55},   
pages = {105-122}   
}
```

But in the pdf output I got this:

`B. Amberg. Artinian and noetherian factorized groups. Rend. Sem. Mat. Univ. Padova 55 (), 105-122`

As you can see, there is no date between brackets! Can you help me with that?

This is the packages I used and the code I wrote to change the bibliography style:

```
\usepackage[autostyle,italian=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{journaltitle}{\textit{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\textbf{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pages}{#1}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{%
  \printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}
```

Thank you very much!

This is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle,italian=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{due.bib}

\begin{document}
  Sia G \cite{amberg:artinian}
  \cleardoublepage
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you post a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/)? A test I ran with your data gave the expected result. Did you get any warnings from Biber; if so, please post them here.

Comment: Instead of the `date` field, you should use `year`.

Comment: If you are using `biblatex`, `date` is an acceptable field name, it might even be preferred by some, because `date = {1995-08}` will parse correctly, but `year = {1995-08}` will not; the `date` field is not compatible to other bibliography packages though.

Comment: I posted a MWE. Are there packages I used that are not compatible?

Comment: Your MWE works for, me what configuration are you using (`biblatex` and `biber` version etc.)? Do you get any errors or warnings? Note also that instead of `\textit{#1}` and `\textbf{#1}` in the `\DeclareFieldFormat` you had better use `biblatex`'s `\mkbibemph{#1}` and `\makebibbold{#1}`.

Comment: The only error I get is:

File "tesi_magistrale.bbl" is wrong format version - expected 2.2

I don't know what it means :/

Comment: That indeed seems to be the problem. The versions of `biblatex` and `biber` do not match and thus do not play together nicely. Delete all temporary files (`.bbl`, `.aux` etc.), update your system and try again.

Comment: The biber version I have is 1.5 ... Do I have to update it to 2.2? How can I do that?

Comment: The newest version of `biblatex` is 2.7a, for `biber` this is 1.7 (see Table 1, p. 6 [here](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) for compatibility). An update works just as usual. What TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10705/discussion-between-rob-and-moewe)

Comment: @Rob Now that the problem is resolved, it might be a good idea to either close the question or post the solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: resolved in the comments after an update